# same IE version on different computers & only one is hiding my dropdown menu

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

The website I am working on displays fine everywhere I have checked it except on my boss's computer where the drop down menus display behind the other content.  Other computers in the office which have the exact same version of IE don't have this problem.  Initially we had this problem on several versions of IE but I fixed it by changing the Z-index.

I just don't know where to start to solve this one.  Anybody have any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks,

Kate

Comment: Sure you boss doesn't have any plugins? Sure everything on the computer is properly updated?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is updated.  Plugins I am not sure on.  I didn't know they could effect display that way.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly likely to be related to Compatibility mode. Open the dev tools (press F12), and check the mode. If it says something different between the two machines, then you've found the problem.

Solution: Add the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag to your page header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

You should also check the browser settings; this tends to happen due to a config setting in IE that tells it to switch to compat mode for sites on the local intranet. Unless you really need it, this setting should be switched off.

Comment: Thanks Spud, that sounds more likely I will check it out.  It might take me a bit since I won't be back in until Mon.